# How to add image into the specific section of the achor tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three images and two anchor tags. When user click on any link then user can select any image.Then this image must be replaced with anchor tag image in which user clicked.

```js
var control3 = document.getElementById('control1').src;
var control4 = document.getElementById('control2').src;

function getImage(e) {
  fullpath = e.children[0].src;

  var filename = fullpath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

  var imageSrc = filename.split("\.")[0] + ".png";

  if (control1 !== fullpath) {
    document.getElementById('control1').src = "images/" + imageSrc;
  }

  if (control2 !== fullpath) {
    document.getElementById('control2').src = "images/" + imageSrc;
  }

  if (control3 !== fullpath) {
    document.getElementById('control3').src = "images/" + imageSrc;
  }
}
```

```html
<img onclick="getImage(this);" src="images/image1.png" alt="">
<img onclick="getImage(this);" src="images/image2.png" alt="">
<img  onclick="getImage(this);" src="images/image3.png" alt="">

<a href=""><img id="control1" src=""></a>
<a href=""><img id="control2" src=""></a>
```

Comment: You forgot to add your JS code

Comment: @ADyson Thanks. I am waiting for you reply. I stuck badly in this section of the website. I tried many different ways to solve problems but I did not find any clue. I will appreciate if you help me.

Comment: Ok, so, I see you have a `getImage` function. But how are you triggering it? I see no code which would make that function run. Did you omit that? Or are you unsure how to write such code? It's a bit unclear. You haven't really described specifically what part(s) of the desired functionality is giving you problems.

Comment: @ADyson basically, firstly  I tried to add images into links but when I click on one image then same image displays into two link at one time. I want defferent image into different link section.

Comment: First two lines in JS: variable and ID naming doesn't match. Then in you function you use control1 and control2 that are undefined. This is where you start with fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've really only implemented part of the process here. You need to consider the flow of the program more carefully:

You need firstly to handle click events on the links.

And you also need to make it possible for users to click on an image to select it for replacement.

Then your code needs to be able to match the clicked image to the clicked link, so it knows what change to make.

N.B. in this demo I've replaced your inline event handlers with *unobtrusive* event handlers using `addEventListener` (i.e. declared in the JS, not embedded in the HTML).

```js
//variables to hold program state
var selectEnabled = false;
var selectedImage = "";

//handle clicks on links
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".imageLink");
links.forEach(function(lnk) {
  lnk.addEventListener("click", enableImageSelection);
});

function enableImageSelection(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //stop the hyperlink doing its normal job (i.e. moving to another page)
  selectEnabled = true;
  alert("Please select an image to replace");
  imageSrc = this.querySelector("img").src;
}

//handle clicks on the replaceable images
var clickableImages = document.querySelectorAll(".clickableImage");
clickableImages.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener("click", loadImage);
});

function loadImage() {
  if (selectEnabled == true) {
    console.log("replacing " + this.src + " with " + imageSrc);
    this.src = imageSrc;
    selectEnabled = false; //image is not clickable again until a link is clicked first.
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="clickableImage" src="images/image1.png" alt="1" />
<img class="clickableImage" src="images/image2.png" alt="2" />
<img class="clickableImage" src="images/image3.png" alt="3" />
<br/><br/>
<a href="" class="imageLink"><img src="images/image4.png"> Click me</a>
<a href="" class="imageLink"><img src="images/image5.png"> Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just last thing, this shows links into images but I want to show images replacing link's images.

Comment: "When user click on any link then user can select any image.Then this image must be replaced with anchor tag image in which user clicked." is what you said in the question. That's what I've implemented. So maybe you described it the wrong way round?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want from your explanation but I guess it's something like this:

1. Have lots of images and two empty "boxes".
2. Click on a box and you can click on an image.
3. The box will update when you clicked on the image.
4. *optional:* make it dynamic, so you can add any amount of images or "boxes".

In order to do so you need to:

1. Know what box you first clicked on.
2. Tell the images you can select between that they can be clicked.
3. Update the original box with the clicked image.
4. *bonus:* give the user feedback (highlights).

```js
var selectedImageId = "";   // 1. Know what box you first clicked on.
const SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME = 'selectable';

// 1. Know what box you first clicked on.
function selectImage(imageElement) {
  let selectableImagesContanier = document.getElementById('selectables');
   if (selectedImageId && selectedImageId != imageElement.id) {
     let prevSelectedImage = document.getElementById(selectedImageId);
     prevSelectedImage.classList.remove(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME);     
   }
     
   selectedImageId = imageElement.id;

   // 4. bonus: give the user feedback (highlights)
   imageElement.classList.add(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME);
   selectableImagesContanier.classList.add(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME);}

function getImage(imageElement) {
  let selectableImagesContanier = document.getElementById('selectables');

  // 2. Tell the images you can select between that they can be clicked.
  if (selectableImagesContanier.classList.contains(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME)) {
    let imageToBeUpdated = document.getElementById(selectedImageId);

    // 3. Update the box with the clicked image.
    imageToBeUpdated.src = imageElement.src;

    // 4. bonus: give the user feedback (highlights)
    selectableImagesContanier.classList.remove(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME);
    imageToBeUpdated.classList.remove(SELECTABLE_CLASS_NAME);
    imageToBeUpdated.classList.add('image-shown');
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#selectables.selectable > img,
img.selectable {
  border-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-image-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.selected-image-container > img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.selected-image-container > img.image-shown {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="selectables">
  <img onclick="getImage(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/50/50" alt="">
  <img onclick="getImage(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/31/50/50" alt="">
  <img onclick="getImage(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/id/41/50/50" alt="">
</div>

<div class="selected-image-container">
  <img id="control1" src="" onclick="selectImage(this)">
  <img id="control2" src="" onclick="selectImage(this)">
</div>
```